# Finitely generated Clifford semigroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

If $S$ is a finitely generated Clifford semigroup, therefore its corresponding semilattice is finitely generated. We know that a finitely generated semilattice is finite. Does this mean that $S$ is finite in this case?
Can someone please help me to understand this?

Comment: It is clear to me that if $S'$ is a large subsemigroup then , $S$ is finitely generated if and only if $S'$ is finitely generated! How can I show that if $S$ is finitely generated Clifford semigroup then any Clifford subsemigroup $S'$ of $S$ is also finitely generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't because it isn't true that a subsemigroup of a Clifford semigroup is finitely generated. For example, every group is a Clifford semigroup, and so, say, the free group with two generators is finitely generated but has non-finitely generated subgroups, and hence subsemigroups.